# Combining two arrays of unequal sizes and storing in a third array as such

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, concatenation

I want to combine two arrays of different sizes into a third array(which is an array of arrays).

I have tried to use np.concatenate function as well as the np.append function but am not getting the desired results.

```
A=[1. 1. 0.] 
B=[0. 1.]

y2=np.concatenate((yl, yr))
```

Expected Result `[[0 1],[1 1 0]]`

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do with the result? 
Just use a list if you want to iterate over the array elements.

```py
import numpy as np
A=np.array([1., 1., 0.]) 
B=np.array([0., 1.])

y2=[A,B]
```

Comment: Better use valid statements. Those are outputs and not array(as it needs commas)

Comment: Oh, I just copied the code from the question. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use np.array here.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1., 1., 0.]) 
B = np.array([0., 1.])

y2 = np.array([A,B])
print(y2)
#output:- array([array([1., 1., 0.]), array([0., 1.])])
```

And for your expected output, you need to convert A and B to list:-

```
v = np.vectorize(int)
y2 = [v(B).tolist(), v(A).tolist()]
print(y2)
#output:- [[0, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
```